# rule for redirect thousands posts with ID query

Tags: redirect, iis, rules

I use windows Server with IIS 7.5. I moved an ASP website with thousands of articles to a WordPress website on the same server under the same domain.

The old address for example for one article looks:

> http://example.com/article.asp?id=38

the new address on wordpress looks:

> http://www.example.com/?page_id=38

I need a rule to redirect (*301 permanent*) all thousands of articles to the new addresses, for example:

- `article.asp?id=38` should go `to?page_id=38`
- `article.asp?id=1289` should go `to?page_id=1289`

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share with us your previous attempts to prove that you have already tried to solve this problem on your own but couldn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the rule below:

```xml
<rule name="redirect sample" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/article.asp" />
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="id=(.*)" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/?page_id={C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide some explanation why do you think your proposed solution might solve OP's problem.

Comment: YES YES YES YES,
it works great. many many many Thanks

Comment: Just another question, is it redirect 301 permanent? if not, please add. Thanks

Comment: In the rule, you can set the redirect type to permanent (301). you can refer to the screenshot above.